# unable to access models in Django Application

Tags: python, django

[image: enter image description heed]

When i try to run following query in the shell i gets following error

```
from flights.models import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flights
```

How should I access my models inside flights app. why I get error No module flights when i have clearly flights app

Comment: is your `.py` file on `apps.py`? If so I think you should `import models` or `from .models import *`

Comment: thanks ,I was not in virtual Env that's why it was unable to find out modules

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Env was not properly configured.I was querying without activating virtual env

Answer (score 0):

With python/Django imports are relative.

Hence you must import as such:

```
from .models import YourModel
```